# Logstash multiple logs

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am following an online tutorial and have been provided with a cars.csv file and the following Logstash config file. My logstash is running perfectly well and is indexing the CSV as we speak.

The question is, I have another log file (entirely different data) which I need to parse and index into a different index.

1. How do I add this configuration without restarting logstash?
2. If above isn't possible and I edit the config file then restart logstash - it won't reindex the entire cars file will it?
3. If I do 2. How do I format the config for multiple styles of log file.

eg. my new log file looks like this:

```
01-01-2017 ORDER FAILED: £12.11 Somewhere : Fraud
```

Existing Config File:

```
    input {
    file {
           path => "/opt/cars.csv"
           start_position => "beginning" 
           sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
         }
     }

    filter {
       csv {
          separator => ","
          columns =>
          [
                "maker",
                "model",
                    "mileage",
                        "manufacture_year",
                            "engine_displacement",
                            "engine_power",
                            "body_type",
                    "color_slug",
                "stk_year",
            "transmission",
                    "door_count",
            "seat_count",
            "fuel_type",
            "date_last_seen",
            "date_created",
            "price_eur"
         ]
    }

    mutate {
       convert => ["mileage", "integer"]
    }
    mutate {
       convert => ["price_eur", "float"]
    }
    mutate {
           convert => ["engine_power", "integer"]
    }
    mutate {
      convert => ["door_count", "integer"]
    }
    mutate {
           convert => ["seat_count", "integer"]
    }
    }

     output {
      elasticsearch {
       hosts => "localhost"

       index => "cars"
       document_type => "sold_cars"
     }

     stdout {}
    }
```

Config file for orders.log

```
    input {
      file {
            path => "/opt/logs/orders.log"
            start_position => "beginning"
            sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
        }
    }

   filter {
       grok {
          match => { "message" => "(?<date>[0-9-]+) (?<order_status>ORDER [a-zA-Z]+): (?<order_amount>£[0-9.]+) (?<order_location>[a-zA-Z]+)( : (?<order_failure_reason>[A-Za-z ]+))?"}
          }

         mutate {
              convert => ["order_amount", "float"]
            }
          }

       output {
       elasticsearch {
               hosts => "localhost"

               index => "sales"
               document_type => "order"
     }

    stdout {}
     }
```

Disclaimer: I'm a complete newbie. Second day using ELK.

Answer (score 0):

For point 1, either in your logstash.yml file, you can set

`config.reload.automatic:true`

Or, while executing logstash with conf file, run it like:

```
bin/logstash -f conf-file-name.conf --config.reload.automatic
```

After doing either of these settings, you can start your logstash and from now on any change you make in conf file will be reflected back.

Answer (score 0):

`2. If above isn't possible and I edit the config file then restart logstash - it won't reindex the entire cars file will it?`

If you use `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"`, Logstash won't remember where is has stopped reading a document and will reindex it at each restart. You'll have to remove this line if you wish for Logstash to remember (see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/plugins-inputs-file.html#_tracking_of_current_position_in_watched_files)).

`3.How do I format the config for multiple styles of log file.`

To support multiple style of log files, you can put tags on the file inputs (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-tags) and then use conditionals (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.5/event-dependent-configuration.html#conditionals) in your file config.

Like this:

```
file {
    path => "/opt/cars.csv"
    start_position => "beginning" 
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    tags => [ "csv" ]
}


file {
    path => "/opt/logs/orders.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
    tags => [] "log" ]
}


if csv in [tags] {
    ...
} else if log in [tags] {
    ...
}
```